# App launch time

Tags: android, automated-tests, performance-testing

Knowing there are ways to get the launch time information with adb logcat like:

```
ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming: +3s534ms (total +1m22s643ms)
```

Or

```
adb logcat -b events -s am_activity_launch_time:I
```

But these measurements are all based on the the first frame of activity displayed. My question is,

1. Is there anyway to measure the launch time, based on the time that the activity finishes all its display (like it requires another 15 frames to have full drawing of window)
2. Also, is there a way to measure the time gap between the time that finger tip touches the icon and, and the time systems awares and respond with onCreate()?

Thank you.